# Duplicate a file, rename it to a several nonsequential name. No scrip experience

Tags: terminal, automator

I have 1 file that I need to duplicate a number of times and then rename those copies to different nonsequential SKU numbers from a list of numbers. I usually use Automator but when I get a large number of SKUs it can get a little tedious and time-consuming.  I read other posts but I don't have any experience with terminal or scrips. Is there an easy way to rename the nonsequential file?  I don't mind going into Terminal I just don't know where to start.
Thank you

Comment: Rename from a list is not a beginner task. You probably want [A Better Finder Rename](https://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/index.html) which has a rename from file list option.